# How to disable Oracle APEX Interactive Grid automatic refresh?

Tags: oracle-apex

Oracle APEX Interactive Grid is always refresh when the region is opened.

I want to disable this behavior. For example, I want the IG to be refreshed only by pressing a special button.I was looking for some property among the attributes of the IG-region, but I didn't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the region is opened" ?

Comment: For example: IG belong to dialog page. When dialog-page start, then refresh of IG start immediately. I don't need so.

Comment: That is not a refresh, it's just the loading of the report. There is no way to render the region but not load the data. I have never heard of such functionality in reports :). You could hide the region and only show it when your conditions are met using a dynamic action.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a page item , P1_EXECUTE_QUERY and set it default to NO.
Then add a condition to your query:

```
:P1_EXECUTE_QUERY = 'YES'
```

Do not forget to add P1_EXECUTE_QUERY to the "Page items to submit" property.

Use to button to execute a dynamic action and set P1_EXECUTE_QUERY to 'YES' and refresh the region.

Comment: I am aware of this possibility. But still, in this case, the refresh will occur. Although a little. But I would like the refresh not to happen at all. However, thanks for the idea. This will be the first thing I'll do if the rest fails.

Comment: the thing is the data is always served by APEX from the server, if you somehow want to not want the grid to refresh/pull data, you have to find a way to cache the result. I was thinking of putting it in the session but that may not be a good idea?

Comment: Make the region invisible initially, and then make it visible? I'll think about it too.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good idea at all, but here's one anyway:

You can perhaps create a static report of what your interactive grid shows at a specific point in time, or a **snapshot stored either as JSON in your database or a BLOB**. For example, you can create a report table as follows:

```
create table IG_REPORT (
  reportid number generated by default on null as identity primary key,
  reportdate date not null,
  report json
)
```

Your interactive grid will then retrieve and display the latest from `IG_REPORT`. You can turn your relational data **to** and **from** JSON. For when you want your interactive grid to be refreshed, you will need to:

- create your own procedure/function that will pull from your original table, and turn the data into JSON
- tie the press of your refresh button to running this procedure/function
- refresh your interactive grid

Sounds like a fun idea! Next question then is, what's the best way to store these point-in-time snapshots of your data? as JSON is just what came to mind at this moment

Comment: It's too complicated in my opinion. But thanks for the idea anyway!